# Cross Domain policy file forActionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, sandbox

I need to access an ASP.Net2 page from Action Script 3.0 and I wrote the code in .fla file that access the asp.net page but there is a problem in the accessing it reports to me the following error :

Error opening URL 'http://localhost/Trial/Default.aspx'
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://localhost/Trial/Default.aspx
    at Script1/sendSQLXML()
    at Script1$iinit()

and after searching I found that it is a problem related to Cross Domain policy so I created an XML file called Crossdomain.xml with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">


<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

and i don't know how to use it from ACS3 and where to put it 
Note: i run the Asp.Net2 page in the IIS

Comment: This is not related to the cross-domain policy file.

Comment: I have solved the problem and the policy file is put when accessing the server remotely but in my problem i found that the data sent in the URL cause the problem due to some wrong sytax that is not accepted in the URL.thx alot for every one and i am too grateful for ur great attention

Answer (score 0):

Look into the loadPolicyFile(..) method: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/system/Security.html#loadPolicyFile()

Comment: i used the following code : Security.loadPolicyFile("http://localhost/Trial/crossdomain.xml");
and it reports to me the following error:
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://localhost/Trial/crossdomain.xml"); and points to the new line of the code that inserted.

Comment: Did you add the import line for the Security class? import flash.system.Security;

Comment: Also just noticed that you have an extra ; at the end. You have .xml";); and it should just be .xml");

Comment: i have imported the required package (flash.system.Securit;) but the problem still exist and report the following error:
Error opening URL 'http://localhost/Trial/Default.aspx'
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://localhost/Trial/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

IF you're working localy (http://localhost/Tri...), i'm not sure that the problem come from some CrossDomain issues...

Comment: so from where the problem come ? are there any checks i have to do?

Comment: in order to help you more, you should post the AS3 code... and tell us what the ASP.net return (text, binary file, stream...?).
cordially,

Comment: i wrote the code of ASC3 and Asp.net code in previous question but no answer at all check it in the foloowing URL:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670702/recieving-data-from-actionscript3-in-asp-net2
and the asp.net code is just :
response.write("test successed");

Comment: ok... your AS3 code seems correct, unfortunatly i don't know ASP.NET... sorry

Answer (score 0):

Typically the crossdomain file gets placed at the root of the server, if you are running locally you shouldn't be having crossdomain issues, but you might want to try placing it in c:\inetput\wwwroot\ and see if that addresses your issue.

Answer (score 0):

crossdomain.xml gets put at the root of the server you are trying to access. that's the default location such that you won't need to call Security.loadPolicyFile()